# Why embed PNG in Action Script looks pixelated when added to a stage?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, png, embed

Here is what I do:

```
 package
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Loading extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="loading.png")]
        private var MyLoading : Class;
        private var spinner:Bitmap;
...

        public function MoxieLoading(center:Point)
        {           
            spinner = new MyLoading;
            addChild(spinner);
...
```

And when my loading png finally appears it looks like a poorly indexed GIF, especially on edges. Why is it happening? I'm using Bitmap class here, maybe there is something better? Can I control quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are there any scaling going on? Try Bitmap smoothing:

```
myBitmap.smoothing = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the png is of good quality;
2. Check if you don't modify `spinner` width, height, scale, filters;
3. Place it on even position, that is `x = 50` not `x= 50.5`;

But overall it seems like a problem with the actual picture, not flash. I never ever had any problems with embeded PNGs, maybe the program in which you saved it did it in some funky way?

Comment: #3 isn't necessary (though it can't hurt) because of pixel snapping: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#pixelSnapping

Comment: Good point, though no one said this property is set, and maybe it's just my bad experiences, but I learned not to trust people (or programs) to have some things set.